# Reset OpenCryptoki SW Token

Tags: linux, cryptography, pkcs#11

I build open cryptoki library from source and try to initialize the software token. 
but when `running pkcsconf -I -c 3` for initializing the token, I get the following Error message:

```
Enter the SO PIN: 
Enter a unique token label: poef
Error initializing token: 0xA4 (CKR_PIN_LOCKED)
```

The token Info looks like this:

```
$ pkcsconf -t
Token #3 Info:
    Label: IBM OS PKCS#11                  
    Manufacturer: IBM Corp.                       
    Model: IBM SoftTok     
    Serial Number: 123             
    Flags: 0xD80045 (RNG|LOGIN_REQUIRED|CLOCK_ON_TOKEN|USER_PIN_TO_BE_CHANGED|SO_PIN_COUNT_LOW|SO_PIN_LOCKED|SO_PIN_TO_BE_CHANGED)
    Sessions: 0/18446744073709551614
    R/W Sessions: 18446744073709551615/18446744073709551614
    PIN Length: 4-8
    Public Memory: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    Private Memory: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    Hardware Version: 1.0
    Firmware Version: 1.0
    Time: 08:07:03
```

So as I understand I should reset the Software Token, to get a default SO PIN and could initialize the token, to use it. But I cannot find anything about that in the official docs.

Comment: Usually it is better to contact the supplier for these kind of very (commercial) product specific questions.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it is a testsetup for myself, so there is no supplier. This is just a testsetup, so I coul dplay around before having to develop against real hardware

Comment: It is an open source project (https://github.com/opencryptoki/opencryptoki) it happens to come from a commercial entity, it doesn't require their hardware, seems quite reasonable to ask an open source community if they know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset everything, you have to delete the content of /var/opencryptoki/swtok

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/com.ibm.linux.z.lxce/lxce_initializing_ep11token.html

I have no familiarity with this specific SW P11 implementation but the command sequence here seems to make sense.

The default pin is 12345678, you would want to change that, initialize the user pin, change that. Theory being that in that sequence you wont be locked.